# Cakephp 2.6 Layouts are not loading only view is rendered

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp version 2.6 . My main issue is only view of a action is rendered ,but layout is not getting applied.It is happening on overall actions.Whether it is a server issue
I have applied default layout in AppController.php ,but still not working

```
public function beforeFilter() {
       $this->layout = 'default';
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first of all `deafult` will loaded automatically. second if you want to do then do either in `beforeRender()` of `App` or go the particular action and there only write `$this->layout = 'some other layout';`

Comment: I have used $this->layout = 'default' in respective actions, but some time it is getting applied and other time only view is rendered.When viewed source only view code is displayed,not of the layout.

Comment: @AsimKatamale have you any type of error like data base not connected etc.

Comment: No database errors, and the code works fine on my local server ,but not on LIVE server and LIVE server PHP version is 5.4

Comment: Just imagine in case where we have added $this->autoRender = false OR $this->layout = null, that type of view is getting displayed, that also on some instances ,other time it works fine

Comment: if your function is ajax type and you write `$this->autoRender = false` then its not possible to get layout in this case. same for `$this->layout = null` . Means in case of ajax function layout will not work

Comment: deleting my answer because it seems  that it not helped you.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **default.ctp** as default layout means, then don't want include the following line.

```
$this->layout = 'default';
```

Because cakephp is render to "`default.ctp`" layout by default.

Incase you want **some other layout** "`someotherlayout.ctp`"

Call to method

```
$this->layout = 'someotherlayout';
```

Suppose, you don't need layout and need some of **main content without layout**. Make sure "`ajax.ctp`" in your layout folder.

```
$this->layout = 'ajax';
```

Suppose, you don't need layout and need **some of main data without layout**.

```
$this->autoRender = false;
//provide the data or redirect some other page
```